# Create a Word document using aspose which contains the mail merge data

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose

I need to create a word serial letter using aspose and i already can create this word document by creating multiple letters and combining them into one document.

But i need to create a word document which uses the mail merge functionality so that the user can change text once for all recipients.

The datasource can be configured in word, but it seems always to be a path to a file.

Question: Is it possible to embed the datafile into the word document?

The goal is to send(email) the word serial letter document including the datasource to a user who then can edit the document content and print it. And the mail merge data should be part of the docx file.

Comment: It's quite clear what is being asked, here, if one knows the Word technology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The data source for Word's built-in mail merge functionality *must* be a separate file (or external database). There's no provision for "embedding" a data source in a Word document.

The closest you can get would be to embed a `CustomXMLPart` in the Word Open XML file (docx, docm, dotx or dotm). That can be any valid XML, using any vocabulary and, optionally, namespace.

Nodes in the XML file can be mapped to `Content controls` placed in the Word document so that the node content is displayed on the document surface. And if the user types into the content control, that will also be written to the Custom XML Part.

I don't know whether aspose supports any of this. The Word interop and the Open XML SDK do. The approach may not help you with the specific project you have in mind, but it's the only option, really, to combine a "data source" with a Word document.